# Почему отбрасывается часть массива?

Tags: java

Необходимо создать ArrayList путём разбивки массива на несколько частей. Дано:

```
String tmp = "number=13.5&name=QWERTY";
String[] array = tmp.split("&");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Далее дроблю array:

```
for (String s : array) 
   list = Arrays.asList(array.split("="));
```

Предполагаю, что на выходе list будет выглядеть: [number, 13.5, name, QWERTY], но вопреки моим ожиданиям на выходе: [name, QWERTY]

Почему так и как исправить? Спасибо.

Comment: `list = Arrays.asList(method.split("="));` один и тот же список перезаписываете?

Comment: да, только я допустил опечатку: вместо method должно быть array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы переписываете ссылку на список в цикле.

Для добавления в список другого списка используйте [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)

```
for (String s : array) 
   list.addAll(Arrays.asList(method.split("=")));
```

Comment: Спасибо! А в случае, если вместо листа используется массив, т.е. разбитые элементы одного массива добавить в другой?

Comment: @ИльяНиколаев, это сложнее, чем списки из-за природы массива. Если именно массив т.е. `String[]`, то нужно будет создать новый массив с большей длиной, чтобы вместить старый массив и другие части, после записать старый массив, а после новый, при этом ненапутав с индексами. В этом случаи, списки более выигрышные -- у них API более дружелюбное, высокоуровневое

Comment: Ясно, пусть будет список)

Comment: @ИльяНиколаев, не забудьте принять ответ :)